# How to save and retrieve photos in photo album with their names

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery, photolibrary

I have the following doubts:

1. Can we save a photo(image) to photo album with a "specific name" or can we access the name of the photo after saving it?
2. Can we access a photo with its name from the photo album?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code for writing images with user specified name

```
 // Create paths to output images
 NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
 NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];

 // Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality)
 // The value 'image' must be a UIImage object
 // The value '1.0' represents image compression quality as value from 0.0 to 1.0
 [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

 // Write image to PNG
 [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

 // Let's check to see if files were successfully written...

 // Create file manager
 NSError *error;
 NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 // Point to Document directory
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

 // Write out the contents of home directory to console
 NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. Actually, I need to save the photos to photo album with specific name, not the document directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using delegate `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` for invoking camera or image library.

**To Invoke Camera:**

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
isCamera = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

**To Invoke Library:**

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController*)picker animated:YES];
```

Once done, delegate method gets called:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

To write image to library use:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(currentImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

or save selected image picked from photo library to `UIImage` and perform further actions on it.

Comment: @JaninAnk: Hi, I know how to use imagePicker and save image etc. But my doubt is, how to save and access those images with specific names.

Comment: Your program is not allowed to save things outside of its "sand box".